# Should I use generics for 3D Points and Vectors when developing a library?

Tags: c#, generics

For some context, I mainly program in C++, but also have experience in writing C# for some very limited applications.

I am developing a library for C# that involves a lot of work with 3D points in space. I intend to use this library in a variety of contexts and want it to be as general as possible, but I'm struggling to lock down exactly how I should handle taking in 3D Points and Vectors without forcing users to explicitly use my Point3D type.

From my experience, most applications have their own implementation for Points, such as Rhino3D or unity's Point3D structs which amount to the same exact type: A struct with X,Y,and Z members. I want to support ALL structs that have X,Y, and Z members, not just one. If it helps, I would use templates were I writing this in C++.

I've been and still am scouring the internet for a solution to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having more context on your exact problem, I would say no you should not use generics in this case. A C# generic method can only reference properties or methods known to exist on `T` at compile time. For example, this method works:

```
public string GetString<T>(T obj) { return obj.ToString(); }
```

The reason that compiles fine is because `ToString()` is defined on `System.Object` and everything inherits that.

For a point-like or vector-like type, you might want something like this:

```
public int GetMagnitude<T>(T vector) {
   return Math.Sqrt(vector.X + vector.Y);
}
```

However, not all types have an `X` and `Y`, so generic constraints are required. Here are the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

What is relevant for your case, is that you need to constrain to types that inherit a base class or implement an interface. Something like:

```
public int GetMagnitude<T>(T vector) where T : IVector {
   return Math.Sqrt(vector.X + vector.Y);
}
```

The problem here is that any possible library you want to use this with would have to make their vector class implement this interface, and there is no commonly used interface for this that would be a safe choice.

---

Possibly of interest is the proposed language feature "Shapes". https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164

This would allow more of a "duck-typing" approach to generics.

This has been in the backlog for a while. It looked like a possible candidate for C#8 early in that development cycle, now it's a possibility for C#9, so don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Just to to be clear, If I were to implement the first generic function you posted (public int GetMagnitude<T>(T vector))  then compile it into a DLL, a client wouldn't be able to use it with their own type since it wasn't defined at the time I compiled my library. Right?

Comment: The first version of `GetMagnitude` wouldn't even compile because `T` is unconstrained, so the `X` and `Y` properties aren't even unavailable. Fixing that is what the second version demonstrates.

Comment: But now you run into the problem that passing a value type as an interface will box the value, and that's not a performance hit you want to take, I imagine.

Comment: I see. And you're right, performance is a concern. So at the end of the day, clients will be forced to convert their types to my types or at the very least add this interface to their types for this to be feasible.

Comment: Feasibility stops even shorter than that. Imagine you have a `Point3D<T>` struct with `X`, `Y`, and `Z` properties of type `T`. You can't do math on those properties. That's a showstopper. Operators are defined in terms of direct IL instructions (for primitives) or static method calls (for overloaded operators), but type constraints only give you access to the *instance* members of the constrained type. You couldn't do math on `Point3D<double>`, for example, simply because you can't add an appropriate interface to `double` to give you the methods you need.

Comment: Wow that's intense. Thanks for the answer and elaboration to my comment.

Comment: @madreflection brings up good points too. There are problems beyond just not compiling here, like interfaces boxing value types, and also being committed to a single value type like int64 for the interface. Sadly no generic math in .NET.